# MergeUtility for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, etl

Here is a utility that supports ETL/merging in Entity Framework.

If it's not appealing as a general purpose tool, why?

If it is appealing as a general purpose tool, how might the design be made better?

Also, I'm not the world's most experienced programmer when it comes to writing re-usable code with paramaterized types - any feedback on that aspect would be appreciated.

```
public static class MergeUtility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: documentation
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TItem">The type of the source items.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TContainer">The type of the destination container.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TTarget">The type of the destination items.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">A function returning an enumerable set of source items.</param>
    /// <param name="container">A function returning a destination container.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceKey">The name of the property on each source item who's value uniquely identifies it in the whole set.</param>
    /// <param name="targetSet">The name of the property on the target container who's value is the ObjectSet containing the target items.</param>
    /// <param name="targetKey">The name of the property on each target item who's value uniquely identifies it in the whole set.</param>
    /// <param name="save">A function called when the merge is completed to save the changes in the target container.</param>
    public static void Merge<TItem, TContainer, TTarget>(
        Func<IEnumerable<TItem>> items,
        Func<TContainer> container,
        string sourceKey,
        string targetSet,
        string targetKey,
        Action<TContainer> save)
        where TItem : class
        where TContainer : IDisposable
        where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        Log<TItem, TContainer, TTarget>();

        var source = items();

        using (var destination = container())
        {
            var target = destination.MemberValue<ObjectSet<TTarget>>(targetSet);

            var existing = target.ToDictionary(c => c.MemberValue<object>(targetKey));

            var mapper = new Mapper<TItem, TTarget>();

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                var id = item.MemberValue<object>(sourceKey);

                TTarget entity;

                if (existing.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    entity = existing[id];
                }
                else
                {
                    entity = new TTarget();
                    target.AddObject(entity);
                }

                mapper.MapProperties(item, entity, false);
            }

            save(destination);
        }
    }

    public static void Merge<TSource, TSourceContainer, TTarget, TTargetContainer>(
        EntitySource<TSource, TSourceContainer> source, 
        EntityTarget<TTarget, TTargetContainer> target)
        where TSource : class
        where TSourceContainer : IDisposable
        where TTarget : class, new()
        where TTargetContainer : IDisposable
    {
        using (var container = source.Container())
        {
            Merge<TSource, TTargetContainer, TTarget>(
                () => container.MemberValue<ObjectSet<TSource>>(source.Set),
                target.Container,
                source.Key,
                target.Set,
                target.Key,
                target.Save);
        }
    }

    public static void Merge<TSource, TContainer, TTarget>(
        Source<TSource> source,
        EntityTarget<TTarget, TContainer> target)
        where TSource : class
        where TContainer : IDisposable
        where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        Merge<TSource, TContainer, TTarget>(
            source.Items,
            target.Container,
            source.Key,
            target.Set,
            target.Key,
            target.Save);
    }

    public static void Merge<T1, T2, T3>()
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class, new()
        where T3 : IDisposable
    {
        Merge(
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<Source<T1>>(),
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<EntityTarget<T2, T3>>());
    }     

    private static void Log<TSource, TContainer, TTarget>()
        where TSource : class
        where TContainer : IDisposable
        where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MERGE");
        Console.WriteLine("       Source: " + typeof(TSource).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("    Container: " + typeof(TContainer).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("       Target: " + typeof(TTarget).FullName);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm using it in my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration.Initialize();
        new Program().ExtractAndStageCakeAffiliates();
    }

    public Program()
    {
        MapperItem.AddConversion<Int32, Decimal>(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c));
        MapperItem.AddConversion<Int32, String>(c => c.ToString());
        MapperItem.AddConversion<Boolean, String>(c => c.ToString());
        MapperItem.AddConversion<Int16, String>(c => c.ToString());
        MapperItem.AddConversion<DateTime, String>(c => c.ToString());
        MapperItem.AddConversion<Decimal, String>(c => c.ToString());
    }

    public void ExtractAndStageCakeAffiliates()
    {
        MergeUtility.Merge(
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<Source<Cake.Data.Wsdl.ExportService.Affiliate>>(),
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<EntityTarget<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>>());
    }

    public void LoadCakeAffiliates()
    {
        MergeUtility.Merge(
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<EntitySource<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>>(),
            ServiceLocator.GetInstance<EntityTarget<Cake.Model.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.CakeContainer>>());
    }

    public void RefreshCakeAffiliates()
    {
        this.ExtractAndStageCakeAffiliates();
        this.LoadCakeAffiliates();
    }
}
```

And here's the DI setup:

```
internal class Configuration
{
    internal static void Initialize()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()

                // Extract from web service
            .RegisterInstance<Source<Cake.Data.Wsdl.ExportService.Affiliate>>(
                new Source<Cake.Data.Wsdl.ExportService.Affiliate>(
                    () => ServiceLocator.GetInstance<Cake.Data.Wsdl.ICakeWebService>().ExportAffiliates(),
                    "affiliate_id"))

                // Load to staging
            .RegisterInstance<EntityTarget<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>>(
                new EntityTarget<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>(
                    () => new Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities(),
                    "CakeAffiliates",
                    "Affiliate_Id",
                    c => c.SaveChanges()))

                // Extract from staging
            .RegisterInstance<EntitySource<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>>(
                new EntitySource<Cake.Model.Staging.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities>(
                    () => new Cake.Model.Staging.CakeStagingEntities(),
                    "CakeAffiliates",
                    "Affiliate_Id"))

                // Load to production
            .RegisterInstance<EntityTarget<Cake.Model.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.CakeContainer>>(
                new EntityTarget<Cake.Model.CakeAffiliate, Cake.Model.CakeContainer>(() =>
                    new Cake.Model.CakeContainer(),
                    "CakeAffiliates",
                    "Affiliate_Id",
                    c => c.SaveChanges())) 
            ;
```

And the object mapper:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This Mapper can transfer the values bwtween two existing objects, the source and the destination.
    /// 
    /// Property names are matched after being normalized:
    ///    1. Underscores are removed (foo_bar_id becomes foobarid).
    ///    2. Converted to uppercase (foobarid becomes FOOBARID)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="S"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class Mapper<S, T>
    {
        List<MemberInfo> targetMembers = new List<MemberInfo>();

        private List<string> ignoreList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> IgnoreList
        {
            get { return ignoreList; }
            set { ignoreList = value; }
        }

        public Mapper()
        {
            this.targetMembers.AddRange(typeof(T).GetProperties());
            this.targetMembers.AddRange(typeof(T).GetFields());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transfer the values bwtween two existing objects, the source and the destination.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The object from which property values will be obtained.</param>
        /// <param name="target">The object who's properties recieve the value of their matching property in the <paramref name="source"/></param>
        /// <param name="failIfNotMatched">When a property in the <paramref name="source"/> does not match to a property in the <paramref name="target"/>
        /// and <paramref name="failIfNotMatched"/> is TRUE, a <c>TargetNotMatchedException</c> will be thrown.  Otherwise the unmatched property is ignored.< </param>
        /// <param name="mapInheritedMembers">When <paramref name="mapInheritedMembers"/> is TRUE the set of source properties will include properties which
        /// are inherited.  Otherwise only the properties of the most derived type are mapped.</param>
        public void MapProperties(S source, T target, bool failIfNotMatched = true, bool mapInheritedMembers = false)
        {
            BindingFlags bindingFlags = mapInheritedMembers
                ? BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
                : BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in source.GetType()
                                                    .GetProperties(bindingFlags)
                                                    .Where(c => !IgnoreList.Contains(c.Name)))
            {
                try
                {
                    var sourceField = Factory.Get<MapperItem>(property, source);
                    var targetField = Factory.Get<MapperItem>(MatchToTarget(property), target);

                    targetField.Assign(sourceField);
                }
                catch (TargetNotMatchedException noMatch)
                {
                    if (failIfNotMatched)
                    {
                        throw noMatch;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private MemberInfo MatchToTarget(MemberInfo member)
        {
            var exactMatch = this.targetMembers.Where(c => c.Name == member.Name);
            if (exactMatch.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                return exactMatch.First();
            }

            var sameAlphaChars = this.targetMembers.Where(c => Normalize(c.Name) == Normalize(member.Name));
            if (sameAlphaChars.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                return sameAlphaChars.First();
            }

            throw new TargetNotMatchedException(member, typeof(T));
        }

        private static string Normalize(string input)
        {
            string normalized = input.Replace("_", "").ToUpper();
            return normalized;
        }
    }
```

MapperItem:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encapsulates an item to be mapped and supports conversion from the souce type to the destination type.
    /// </summary>
    public class MapperItem
    {
        private MemberInfo memberInfo;
        private object target;
        private Type type;
        private static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Func<object, object>> Conversions = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Func<object, object>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor. TODO: improve comment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="member"></param>
        /// <param name="target"></param>
        public MapperItem(MemberInfo member, object target)
        {
            this.memberInfo = member;
            this.target = target;
            this.type = this.memberInfo.UnderlyingType();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transfers the value from one mapper item to the other while applying type conversion.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        public void Assign(MapperItem source)
        {
            this.memberInfo.Assign(this.target, source.Convert(this.type));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows arbitrary conversions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="S"></typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="converter"></param>
        public static void AddConversion<S, T>(Func<object, object> converter)
        {
            Conversions.Add(Tuple.Create(typeof(S), typeof(T)), converter);
        }

        private object Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.memberInfo.Value(this.target);
            }
        }

        private object Convert(Type convertToType)
        {
            object converted = null;

            if (this.Value == null)
            {
                return converted;
            }
            else if (convertToType.IsAssignableFrom(this.type))
            {
                converted = this.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                var conversionKey = Tuple.Create(this.type, convertToType);

                if (Conversions.ContainsKey(conversionKey))
                {
                    converted = Conversions[conversionKey](this.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(convertToType.Name + " is not assignable from " + this.type.Name);
                }
            }

            return converted;
        }
    }
```

Reflection extensions:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static Type UnderlyingType(this MemberInfo member)
    {
        Type type;
        switch (member.MemberType)
        {
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                type = ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType;
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                type = ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType;
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Event:
                type = ((EventInfo)member).EventHandlerType;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("member must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", "member");
        }
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
    }

    public static object Value(this MemberInfo member, object target)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            return (member as PropertyInfo).GetValue(target, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            return (member as FieldInfo).GetValue(target);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("member must be either PropertyInfo or FieldInfo");
        }
    }

    public static void Assign(this MemberInfo member, object target, object value)
    {
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            (member as PropertyInfo).SetValue(target, value, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            (member as FieldInfo).SetValue(target, value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("destinationMember must be either PropertyInfo or FieldInfo");
        }
    }

    public static T MemberValue<T>(this object source, string memberName)
    {
        return (T)source.GetType().GetMember(memberName)[0].Value(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a suitable *Contrib project?

Comment: I would remove the DI library dependency, if it exists. Generally, reusable code has as few dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In this object method I would change a couple of things

> ```
>     private object Convert(Type convertToType)
>     {
>         object converted = null;
>
>         if (this.Value == null)
>         {
>             return converted;
>         }
>         else if (convertToType.IsAssignableFrom(this.type))
>         {
>             converted = this.Value;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             var conversionKey = Tuple.Create(this.type, convertToType);
>
>             if (Conversions.ContainsKey(conversionKey))
>             {
>                 converted = Conversions[conversionKey](this.Value);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 throw new Exception(convertToType.Name + " is not assignable from " + this.type.Name);
>             }
>         }
>
>         return converted;
>     }
> ```

I would return directly and get rid of the Object variable.

```
private object Convert(Type convertToType)
{
    if (this.Value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (convertToType.IsAssignableFrom(this.type))
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        var conversionKey = Tuple.Create(this.type, convertToType);

        if (Conversions.ContainsKey(conversionKey))
        {
            return Conversions[conversionKey](this.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(convertToType.Name + " is not assignable from " + this.type.Name);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

we were discussing this question in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and thought that it would be a good idea to turn this method into a Generic Method like so

```
private T Convert<T>(objectToConvert)
{
    if (this.Value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (convertToType.IsAssignableFrom(this.type))
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        var conversionKey = Tuple.Create(this.type, convertToType);

        if (Conversions.ContainsKey(conversionKey))
        {
            return Conversions[conversionKey](this.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(convertToType.Name + " is not assignable from " + this.type.Name);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```